# Titulos junto com imagem utilizando flexbox

Tags: html5, css3

Estou criando uma área de postagens no meu site (html5 e css3), para fazer o layout dela utilizei flexbox, consegui colocar as imagens tudo certo, porém estou tendo problemas para colocar os titulos dos posts em baixo dessas imagens, pois eles quebram o layout, faz uma bagunça enorme.

Como está ficando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu desejo que fique:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML5:

```
     <main>
        <h3 class="postagens">Postagens</h3>
        <div id="postagens">
            <div class="post1">
                <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
                <h3>Titulo da primeira imagem</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="post2">
                <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="post3">
                <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="post4">
                <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="post5">
                <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="post6">
                <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

CSS3:

```
.postagens {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:26px;
    margin-top:100px;
    text-align: center;
}

#postagens {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#postagens img {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:360px;
    height:250px;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara vc esta colocando `margin-bottom` na imagem, e deveria na verdade colocar essa margem no *container* em que a imagem está dentro na verdade.

Para colocar a margem no *container* que a imagem está dentro eu usei um seletor que pega qualquer elemento que comece com a classe `post...` e coloca o `margin-botton` nele

```
[class^="post"] {
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.postagens {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:26px;
    margin-top:100px;
    text-align: center;
}

#postagens {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#postagens img {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:360px;
    height:250px;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-right:30px;
}

[class^="post"] {
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h3 class="postagens">Postagens</h3>
  <div id="postagens">
      <div class="post1">
          <img src="https://www.placecage.com/100/100">
          <h3>Titulo da primeira imagem</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="post2">
          <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="post3">
          <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="post4">
          <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="post5">
          <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="post6">
          <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
      </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Está bem inconsistente seu código, principalmente o CSS. Não entendi o uso de várias classes com nomes em sequência: `post1`, `post2`, `post3` etc., quando, ao meu ver, deveria usar uma só classe para todos, como `post`, por exemplo.

Você poderia fazer da forma abaixo, corrigindo o CSS e eliminando várias propriedades desnecessárias:

```css
.postagens {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:26px;
    text-align: center;
}

#postagens {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
#postagens img {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100%;
    height:250px;
}

.post{
   width:360px;
   padding: 30px 30px 0 30px;
}

.post h3{
   padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h3 class="postagens">Postagens</h3>
  <div id="postagens">
      <div class="post">
          <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
          <h3>Estou criando uma área de postagens no meu site (html5 e css3), para fazer o layout dela utilizei flexbox</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="post">
          <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
          <h3>Estou criando uma área de postagens</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="post">
          <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
          <h3>Estou criando uma área de postagens</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="post">
          <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
          <h3>Estou criando uma área de postagens</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="post">
          <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
          <h3>Estou criando uma área de postagens</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="post">
          <img src="../image/postagem.jpg">
          <h3>Estou criando uma área de postagens</h3>
      </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Utilizei várias classes para cada post pois mais pra frente irei colocar um gerenciador em php para adicionar os posts de forma mais simples

Comment: Mesmo assim não me parece ser a melhor forma. De qq forma, boa sorte aí.